# Triggering JS from PHP or find loaded URL ( HTMLsimpledom )

Tags: php, javascript, xml, web-scraping

I am using [HTMlsimpledom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to scrap an old website for a client who no longer has the access to the DB,.

The site is a coding nightmare where there are almost no usable classes, and it uses tables mostley.

( To make things a bit more complicated -  the site is in some foreign language which produces strange characters unknown to me. (but thats a sidenote , not a real problem) )

Anyhow - All is fine and working , except that on ONE category of pages, it has a JS anchor trigger to open a phone number in some sort of distorted/ oldfashioned Ajax / JS .

the link presents like this :

```
<a class="icon1 clickTip" onclick="showIndexPhone(1517);showIndexMobile(1517);" title="">Phone</a>
```

So of course I went to search the `showIndexPhone()` function which is :

```
function showIndexPhone(id)
{
/*var oContent = oValue = null;
if ((oContent = document.getElementById("IndexPhone_" + id)) && (oValue = document.getElementById("IndexPhoneValue_" + id)))
{
oContent.innerHTML = oValue.innerHTML;*/
/*var oCounter = new Image();
oCounter.src = "./ctr.asp?id=" + id + "&type=2";*/
var xmlDoc = dbsRequest("./ctr.asp?id=" + id + "&type=2");
//}
}
```

So apparently the `showIndexPhone()` will just construct a simple `URL` that will look like :

```
 http://123.xxx/ctr.asp?id=1517&type=3
```

.. and will also show on the firebug console where `id` is the article id and the `type` is the info type (phone,fax,name etc..)

and then pass it to yet another function `dbsRequest(URL)` which looks like so :

```
function dbsRequest(URL) {
try {
var xmlHTTP;
if (dbsBrowserType == "ie") { // code for IE
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open("GET",URL, false);
xmlHTTP.send(null);
return xmlHTTP.responseXML.documentElement;
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
xmlHTTP.open("GET",URL, false);
xmlHTTP.send();
return xmlHTTP.responseXML.documentElement;
}
}
else if (dbsBrowserType == "ns" || dbsBrowserType == "op") { // code for Mozilla, Opera.
//netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHTTP.open("GET",URL, false);
xmlHTTP.send(null);
return xmlHTTP.responseXML.documentElement;
}
}
catch (e) {
//if (dbsBrowserType == "ie")
// alert("error: " + e.description);
//else if (dbsBrowserType == "ns" || dbsBrowserType == "op")
// alert("error: " + e);
return null;
}
}
```

And then I just got stuck.

I am extremly bad in JS , AJAX and the like, and when I saw that the response is actually some form of XML - I just got stuck. I got about 13,000 entries - and manually clicking each is not really an option..

**Is there any way of getting those fields which are triggered by that JS** ?

Or alternatively , **is there a way to find/construct the URL of the response and parse it to php ??**

**EDIT I**

A real live page example can be found here :

http://123.org.il/?pg=indx_entry&CategoryID=171&ArticleID=1517

I have no idea what language it is, but anyhow you need to click on the green phone icon to the right to see the result phone ..

Comment: In 2013 almost nobody writes raw `javascript`. Your `dbsRequest` has number of flaws; Xhr doesn't work properly in IE, Xhr throws an exception in firefox sometimes when you do not expect it; Xhr has some memory leaks... Why not to use `Jquery-ajax`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response to that AJAX request is just raw XML data. `showIndexPhone()` is retrieving the data and setting the variable `xmlDoc` to it, but it's not doing anything else with it. It's doesn't actually show it anywhere, despite the function name.

Anyway, you can use `file_get_contents()` in PHP to download the XML data, and then use one of its several XML parsers to deconstruct it. There's a whole chapter in the Programming PHP book explaining how to process XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if it does not show anything, how come it shows on the screen ? (I must have missed something, like I said, my skills are quite modest) . Anyhow, please see my Edit I for a live sample page ..

Comment: I don't know. `showIndexPhone()` just sets a variable to what `dbsRequest()` returns, and `dbsRequest()` just returns the XML that comes from AJAX. Neither of them puts anything on the screen. BTW, the language is Hebrew (the country domain .il is Isreal).

Comment: Ok, so how am I supposed to get the XML then ? How to know what URL to go using `file_get_contents()` like you suggested  ? just use `file_get_contents('http://123.xxx/ctr.asp?id=1517&type=3');` ? manually going to this URL with a browser returns an empty HTML..

Comment: The pop-up is apparently coming from the _Pics/Common/tooltip.js plugin. It presumably calls the `onclick` function itself and turns the returned data into a tooltip.

Comment: I also can't get anything from that URL. I tried sending the same cookie, user-agent, and referer that the browser sends, but it didn't work. I'm not sure what we're missing.

Comment: well, If you saw the code of the page , you obviously see that we are dealing with a very very bad coder or at least unpredictable. I just can not figure out how the script work and how to get that phone number in an automated way . there must be some kind of way to achieve that , unfortunately my skills are no match for that particular coder . to me the code seems more like a pile of hacks than a real logical process..

Comment: Most of the code is just third-party plugins, so you get lots of different styles because they came from different programmers. There's nothing fancy or complicated in any of this, dbsRequest() is just dealing with cross-browser compatibility issues. There must be something that `ctr.asp` is checking that I can't figure out.

Comment: Well. In one try I found `http://123.org.il/GetUserDetails.asp` which seems to be a real XML . But I do not know how to pass the parameters . I tried  `http://123.org.il/GetUserDetails.asp?id=1517&type=3` but it come back  empty ..

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that by pure chance, while scrapping and making a small mistake, I found out that the phone is actually in the `title` attribute of the `a` tag.. Probably gets hidden with js when approached from a browser but in direct scraping it appears.. apparently the whole js loops is a hoax or a bad coding indeed,. Anyhow - Thanks a bunch for investing the time to help and investigate . I would still love to know if there is a way to trigger JS while scrapping ..

Comment: "trigger JS" doesn't make sense. Javascript runs in the client, so you either need to load the page in a Javascript-capable browser, or run a standalone Javascript interpreter. PHP doesn't know anything about JS by itself.

Comment: yep, i know. I did not say `php`specifically. but just if there is any way to "emulate" behavior like this . I know there are scrapping software that do so, but it would just be nice to know if there is some way of achieving it in runtime ..